# Android Showcaseview button

Tags: android

I am useing the following xml to syle my showcaseview, but for some reason the button is darker then the original image, any idea?

```
<style name="ShowcaseButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/continueknop</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomShowcaseTheme" parent="ShowcaseView">
    <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#AA010101</item>
    <item name="sv_showcaseColor">@color/actionbar</item>
    <item name="sv_buttonText">Continue</item>
    <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/CustomTitle</item>
    <item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/Customdesc</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTitle" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
<style name="Customdesc" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```